# AutoDesk Infrastructure Studio cannot access Map Server (Windows + IIS)

Tags: autodesk

After restarting the entire server I continue to get this error when accessing any mapagent service (e.g. `http://myserver/mapserver2013/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&request=getcapabilities`).  Although the error does a good job at suggesting the problem there is no help for how to actually fix the problem.  I suspect Map Server is not running...but how do I confirm and fix that?

> Problem: Cannot establish connection to the Infrastructure Map Server.
>
> Possible Causes:
>   -Your session has been idle for too long;
>   -Infrastructure Map Server is no longer responding;
>   -Internet connection problems.
>
> Solution: Restart your application / session, restart the
>   Infrastructure Map Server service, or contact with the server
>   administrator.

Also, when I perform Site Authentication in Audodesk Infrastructure Studio I get an error saying:

> Unable to connect to Map Server.  Please ensure that the server
>   process is running and firewall rules have been set correctly.

I don't know what the server process is called.  I see nothing related to autodesk/mapserver/mapguide under services.

Comment: Can you see if the services are running? I'm not sure about the new Infrastructure Server, but MapGuide used to need both its own service and its apache instance running. They might not be configured to start with the OS

Comment: This is running under IIS...the IIS service is reporting the error above.  Is apache still required?

Comment: I assume this means the Infrastructure Map Server 2013 service is running? Sorry but beyond this suggestion I can't really help. I've never had the time or the patience for this product in its various incarnations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the service `infrastructure mapserver2013`

is up and running (run services.msc from your start menu). If you are running a trial version: make sure your license has not stopped.
In general: check `program files\autodesk\autodesk infrastructure map server\logs` for any clues why your service is not started.

You better check by using `http://myserver/mapserver2013/mapagent/index.html` rather than explicitely using the WFS service.

I've noticed that infrastructure map server does not always start on boot because the actual start is too slow: in the service configuration you can set that it will retry starting after one minute.